# Estimating $\sum\limits_{n\leq x} d_3(n)$.

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

If $d_3(n)$ denotes the number of ways to write $n$ as a product of $3$ positive integers then how do I show that as $x\to \infty$, $\sum\limits_{n\leq x}d_3(n)=\frac{x(\log x)^2}{2}+O(x\log x)$. Further how to refine this to obtain a secondary main term of the form $cx\log x$ for some constant $c$ and an error term $o(x\log x)$??

Comment: The fancy way is to note that the Dirichlet series associated to $d_3(n)$ is $\zeta(s)^3$, then use Perron's formula. The less fancy way is to use a variant of the Dirichlet hyperbola method.

Comment: There is some discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function

Comment: Apply two times Dirichlet hyperbola one time for $D_2(x)=\sum_{md \le x} 1$ then for $D_3(x)=\sum_{l \le x} D_2(x/l)$, this is how $D_k(x) = x P_k(\log x)+O(x^{1-1/k}\log^{k-2}(x))$ is obtained. See Tichmarsh for how to use Perron's formula and $\zeta(s) = O(t^\epsilon)$